# How to fetch value of input radio button through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fetch the value from input radio button which is present in the table.
I want to fetch the value using iteration and I tried with this code, but I am not getting how to fetch as I am new to jQuery. Please help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".a").click(function() {
    alert(4);
    $("table").find('tr').each(function(i, el) {
      var $tds = $(this).find('td');
      console.log($tds);
      $temp = $('el').find('input[type="radio"]');
      for (x in $temp) {

        if ($("x").is(":checked")) {
          console.log($("x").val());
        }
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type=radio value=1>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type=radio value=2>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type=radio value=3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class='a' type='submit' name='submit'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Those radio buttons should all have the same `name`, otherwise their purpose is pretty redundant. Also in that case you wouldn't need to iterate over them as you could just get the value from the selected one

Answer (score 0):

Why so long? Just get with selector `table input[type=radio]:checked` to get the checked radios only and you don't need to use `is(':checked')` anymore.

For performance Use just `el.value`, not `$(el).val()` for getting the value

```js
$(".a").click(function () {
     $("table input[type=radio]:checked").each(function (i, el) {        
         console.log(el.value);  
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type=radio value=1>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=radio value=2>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=radio value=3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class='a' type='submit' name='submit'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

But if your radios are in the same group, add `name` to them for grouping and just use `$("table input[type=radio]:checked").val()`.

```js
$(".a").click(function () {
   console.log($("table input[type=radio]:checked").val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type=radio name="group" value="1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=radio name="group" value="2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=radio name="group" value="3">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class='a' type='submit' name='submit'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank u  so much sir

Comment: @abhi if this helps, you can accept this to help others find it easily

Answer (score 0):

You need to have name, id or class to access the values

Please check the code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".a").click(function () {
    
             var radioValue = $("input[name='radio_name']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue){
                alert("You have chosen " + radioValue);
            }
           
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="radio_name" type=radio value=1>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="radio_name" type=radio value=2>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="radio_name" type=radio value=3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class='a' type='submit' name='submit'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```